# Meteor app connect to localhost mongodb

Tags: android, mongodb, meteor

On my local computer i've got a meteor applicatie up and running on localhost:3000 and mongodb runs on localhost:3001.

Now i wanna run my meteor application on my android phone. I want that the meteor application on my phone is connected to the mongodb database on my computer(localhost:3001).

When i run my app i use this command:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://user:password@internalipadres:3001/meteor" meteor run android-device
```

Is this even possible? Anyone idea's what it could be?
Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you understand that only your *Server* connects to your MongoDB. Your Client (whether Browser or Android app) only receives data through your Server.

What you describe is a very common use case. But once again, it is actually the Server that connects to the local MongoDB.